# React : Possible to do one state render only when another has completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, asynchronous, react-hooks

I want to change state value of a react state variable only when the previous state change has completed. Is it possible to achieve this since setState in react hooks is asynchronous ?

```
  const [err1, setErr1] = useState(false);
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});


  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const url = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apikey}&q=${loc}&aqi=yes`;
  const foo = await fetch(url);
  const data = await foo.json();
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
      setErr1(true);
   } else {
      setErr1(false);  
      setWeather(data); //I want to Change Weather only when Err1 has been changed
   }
   };
```

Comment: Any specific reason that you want 2 re-renders ? First for setting error and second for weather

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I pass both weather and err1 as props to a Weather Card component. So if the error is true I will display an error message and similarly the opposite.

Comment: I think since handleSubmit is async, React won't batch updates and `err1` will be set first causing a render and then `weather`. Not sure if React has started batching updates for async stuff to but it was said that they will from 17 and onwards sometime. Still not good depending on that. `useEffect` will come into picture here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of useEffect,useRef to achieve the result that you want

```
const dataRef= useRef(null);
useEffect(()=> {
   if (err1 === false && dataRef.current !== null) {
        setWeather(dataRef.current);
        dataRef.current = null;
   }
}, [err1]);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const url = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apikey}&q=${loc}&aqi=yes`;
  const foo = await fetch(url);
  const data = await foo.json();
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
      setErr1(true);
   } else {
      setErr1(false);  
      dataRef.current = data;
   }
};
```

However since both of your states are kind of dependent, it is better if you set them together instead of serializing them unless you want to achieve some specific behavior by serializing

Comment: just a follow ,How do I go on setting them together ? Is it even possible since JS is single-threaded.

Comment: setting them together just means calling `setErr1(false);  
      setWeather(data);` or you can just create a single state which is an object with weather and error properties.